# Best way to disable all styles, scripts and meta tags in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a blog (using **`twentyfifteen`** child theme) and a page where I have to disable all styles, scripts and meta tags which are added by WordPress except meta tags which are added by **All in One Seo Pack plugin.**

I'm new in Wordpress, I tried to use `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false)` in template of this page and nothing happened (visually). I know that there are functions like `wp_dequeue_style()`, but I can't check in **functions.php** whether current page is the page described above.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You can add in your `functions.php` file a conditional `is_pag()` and put your page ID inside and dequeue all the styles there. Something like `if(is_page(2)){wp_dequeue_style(......);}`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Should I do this (wp_dequeue_style(), etc.) for every tag? Is there more general way?

Comment: @ЕвгенийМайстренко please check my answer if it was helpful, please accept

Answer (score 3):

There are two functions

1. `style_dequeue_function()` it will remove all Styles.
2. `script_dequeue_function()` it will remove all Scripts.

All you need to provide page slug or template name.

> `$pageSlug` where you want to hide WordPress styles and scripts.

**OR**

> `$Template_Name` By Template Name

And `remove_action` will remove WordPress generator tag.

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
```

> **Note : It will only `deque` style or scripts which was added by WP enque functions.**

for e.g :

```
wp_register_script( 'site', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/site.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'site' );
wp_register_style( 'screen', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css', '', '', 'screen' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'screen' );


function style_dequeue_function()
{
    global $wp_styles;

    $array = array();
    // Runs through the queue styles
    foreach ($wp_styles->queue as $handle) :
        $array[] = $handle;
    endforeach;

    wp_dequeue_style($array);
    wp_deregister_style($array);

}


function script_dequeue_function()
{
    global $wp_scripts;
    $array = array();
    // Runs through the queue scripts
    foreach ($wp_scripts->queue as $handle) :
        $array[] = $handle;
    endforeach;

    wp_dequeue_script($array);
    wp_dequeue_script($array);
}


add_action( 'wp_head', 'HideWpGeneratorAndScripts' );
function HideWpGeneratorAndScripts()
{

    $pageSlug = "Your Page Slug here.";
    $Template_Name = "Your Custom Template Name here.";

    if(is_page($pageSlug)) {
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'style_dequeue_function');
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_dequeue_function');
        remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');

    }
    else if(is_page_template($Template_Name)) {
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'style_dequeue_function');
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_dequeue_function');
        remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
    }
}
```